# React - Unregistering a registered service worker

Tags: reactjs, webpack, service-worker

I'm developing a React web-app (https://timatorg.is - in case someone wants to look at the response headers) created using create-react-app. At the time it was created, a service worker was registered by default and I didn't really think much about it. The app is hosted at Netlify and the DNS is at Cloudflare.

Now when deploying updates to the website, users that have visited the site before always get the same version of the app and I'm pretty sure it's because of the service worker. But the strange thing is that it's only "https://www.timatorg.is" that is causing issues, not "https://timatorg.is"

I've read a lot of material about how to unregister an already cached service worker but all I've found is a solution that the client can perform in his/her browser but nothing that I can do to solve this for all of our clients.

So my question is, how do I get rid of the service worker? Or more general, push the latest update of our app to our clients?

Answer (score 10):

You can change to the following in your `index.js` file, like the [comment in a new Create React App project says](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/src/index.js#L8):

```
import { unregister } from './serviceWorker';

// ...

unregister();
```

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried that without success. I think the service worker itself is cached if that makes any sense.

Comment: @GunnarTorfiSteinarsson Yes, you're right. The service worker is registered in your users' browsers if you've used `register` before. `unregister` removes it entirely, though. If you build you app again, the main JS bundle will get a new hash, the users will download it, and `unregister` will remove it for them.

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense to me but it's still not working. Note, only for www - it works fine without it.

Comment: @GunnarTorfiSteinarsson Alright, interesting. It's hard to say, but it might also be e.g. an nginx configuration that is caching too aggressively, so the users on www are not getting the new JS file?

Comment: Could be. I'm just not sure how much control I have over it on Netlify.

Comment: @GunnarTorfiSteinarsson Alright. You could inspect the JS sent to the www domain and see if it has `unregister` in it, or if an old script is being sent instead. That could give some clues.

Comment: From a client that's experiencing this issue: In main.xxx.js, unregister is never mentioned. But in 2.xxx.js, there's a mention of unregister but I'm not sure if that's the one or some other unregister function. I also noticed that the client has a whole other hash than me in those main.xxx.js and 2.xxx.js filenames.

Comment: I also noticed that the service-worker.js file that is generated after running "react-scripts build" is not the same as in my project's source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190399/discussion-between-gunnar-torfi-steinarsson-and-tholle).

Comment: Did you guys get any lead in here? I'm stuck with same issue

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code into your index.js file:

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
    registration.unregister();

    if (caches) {
      // Service worker cache should be cleared with caches.delete()
      caches.keys().then(async (names) => {
        await Promise.all(names.map(name => caches.delete(name)));
      });
    }
  });
}
```